# how to store the data after executing the the query in java

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, db2

This is my stored procedure call after  jdbcCall.execute(in) successfully how will I return the response?  Currently, I am getting `null` as the response.

```
public SPDynamicReportResponseDomain getSpResult() {
    SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("app").withProcedureName("GetDatareport");

    jdbcCall.declareParameters(

            new SqlParameter("INREPORTID", Types.INTEGER),
            new SqlParameter("INVIEW", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INDATE", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INTYPE", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INCTL1", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INCTL2", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INCTL3", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INCTL4", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INCTL5", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INFROMBODY", Types.VARCHAR),
            new SqlParameter("INLANG", Types.VARCHAR)
            );

    Map<String, Object> inParamMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    inParamMap.put("INREPORTID", 528);
    inParamMap.put("INVIEW", "YM");
    inParamMap.put("INDATE", "2018-08-12");
    inParamMap.put("INTYPE", null) ;
    inParamMap.put("INCTL1", "PL_01");
    inParamMap.put("INCTL2",null );
    inParamMap.put("INCTL3", "KPI_01_PL_01_1" );
    inParamMap.put("INCTL4", "mitZeitSchranke");
    inParamMap.put("INCTL5", "0");
    inParamMap.put("INFROMBODY", null);
    inParamMap.put("INLANG", "DE");
    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValues(inParamMap);

    Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = jdbcCall.execute(in);
    System.out.println(simpleJdbcCallResult);
    in.getValue(sql);



    dynamicReportResponseDomain.setClusterId1((Integer) simpleJdbcCallResult.get("CLUSTERID2"));
    dynamicReportResponseDomain.setClusterId2((Integer) simpleJdbcCallResult.get("CLUSTERID2"));
    dynamicReportResponseDomain.setClusterId3((Integer) simpleJdbcCallResult.get("CLUSTERID3"));



    return dynamicReportResponseDomain;
}
```

Comment: **Where** are you getting `null` as a response?

Comment: What kind of result do you expect? An output parameter? A result set?